# Speaker not shown on Sound settings (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, sound, ubuntu-gnome, headphones, soundcard

"Speakers" is not shown in sound settings if headphones are plugged in. So, I cannot switch between speakers and headphone unless I unplug headphone.

[image: Sound settings]

I installed PulseAudio volume control and I can switch headphone to speakers using it. But it's weird because it says: `Speakers (unavailable)`. Maybe the problem is about it?

I have searched it but most of the questions about speakers/headphones are not working. In my case, both are working but cannot switch using default sound settings.

[image]

Asus N551VW, Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3, Realtek ALC668 audio driver.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem following these steps:

Added this line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

And then reloaded alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
pulseaudio -k
```

But it didn't change anything. I restarted the machine to make sure and somehow it is resolved.

You can find your sound card model using `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` and its related model code from this file: https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst

Comment: Unfortunately, the github link now 404s, but a quick search for HD-Audio-Models results in a number of hits, including https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

Comment: They moved the file to https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

look in `alsamixer` playback controls

There is probably an option in Playback setting called auto-mute. change setting to 'disabled' to have sound from both speakers and headphones

Comment: thanks for the response. But it's already disabled.

Comment: use command 'aplay -l' in terminal to list audio devices (and paste response to your first post). If response shows only 1 analog sub-device for playback, you can only switch between speakers and headphones and not have both active independently

Comment: Wonderful. I had been groping for solution. Your answer worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a crucial hint in https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/

`pavucontrol` (or: speaker symbol on the panel -> `Audio mixer`) has a - for some silly reason usually hidden - tab named `Configuration`.
Choose there a profile that includes the speaker output, e.g., `Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output`.

Shame that there is no hint on the `Output Devices` tab that the availability of the Speakers etc. output depends on the settings in `Configuration`.